# Ошибка: "unexpected T_STRING"

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно по запросу вывести новости из базы данных. Но столкнулся с непонятной проблемой синтаксиса.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$news="";
ob_start();
require_once "conf.php";
$zapros1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
while ($rezult=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1)){
echo "<div class="accordion"> ";
echo ("<p> {$rezult['text']} </p>");
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Системе не нравится 9 строка  (`echo "<div class="accordion"> ";`) пишет

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\bol\news.php on line 9`

В чем ошибка, не пойму.

Comment: Вы бы потратили хоть 10 минут на то чтобы понять в чем ошибка.. Ан нет.. лучше сразу вопросик на хэшкод.. Не есть гуд.

Comment: Чувствую я самому мне не разобраться в этом помогите если можете у меня примерно такая же ощибка что и у автора передыдущего сообшеия Ошибка синтаксического анализа: синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданный T_STRING  

Comment: @slavacomb, не надо задавать вопросы в комментариях. Создайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно предположить, что вам нужно либо экранировать двойные ковычки (`echo "<div class=\"accordion\">"`), либо использовать одинарные. Иначе парсер полагает, что вы прерываете строку после `class=`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я совсем забыл что вложение двойных кавычек в двойные не есть хорошо .. ... .. . .. .

Comment: Используйте нормальную среду разработки (Eclipse, NetBeans) это избавит от такого рода глупых  вопросов..